# make divs with an resizeable width on both sides

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some trouble making my divs resizeable.
Im trying to make a time scheduler, but the divs should be resizeable and change width based on the resized one.
This is what I currently have now.

```js
var stepsize = 5;
  var min = 0;
  var max = 1440;
  var stepwidth = 100 / max;

  let original_width = 0;
  let original_height = 0;
  let original_x = 0;
  let original_y = 0;
  let original_mouse_x = 0;
  let original_mouse_y = 0;


  console.log(stepwidth);
var timeblocks = {0: [50, 100, "red"], 1: [100, 200, "blue"], 2: [200, 400, "red"]};
calcwidth(timeblocks);
function calcwidth(timeblocks){
  
  const values = Object.values(timeblocks)
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var int = 0;
  var startmargin = 0;
  for (const arrayv of values) {
    
    console.log(arrayv);
    var start = 0;
    var end = 0;
    if(int == 0){
      start = stepwidth * arrayv[0];
      console.log(start);
      end = stepwidth * arrayv[1] - start;
      startmargin = startmargin + (start + end);
    }
    else{
      start = startmargin;
      end = stepwidth * arrayv[1] - start;
      startmargin = startmargin + (end);
    }
    
    
    console.log(startmargin);
    var timeblock = document.createElement('div');
    timeblock.className = "timeblock";
    timeblock.style.background = arrayv[2];
    timeblock.style.marginLeft = start + "%";
    timeblock.style.width = end + "%";

    var moverleft = document.createElement('div');
    moverleft.style.width = "5px";
    moverleft.style.height = "50px";
    moverleft.style.background = "black";
    moverleft.style.marginLeft = "0px";
    moverleft.style.position = "absolute";
    moverleft.style.opacity = "0.4";
    moverleft.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      original_width = timeblock.style.marginLeft;
      original_x = timeblock.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      original_mouse_x = e.pageX;
      console.log(original_width);
      moverleft.addEventListener('mousemove', resize);
      moverleft.addEventListener('mouseup', stopResize);
      
    });

    var moverright = document.createElement('div');
    moverright.style.width = "5px";
    moverright.style.height = "50px";
    moverright.style.background = "black";
    moverright.style.right = "0px";
    moverright.style.position = "absolute";
    moverright.style.opacity = "0.4";


    timeblock.appendChild(moverleft);
    timeblock.appendChild(moverright);

    container.appendChild(timeblock);
    
    int++;
  }



}

    function resize(e) {
      const width = original_width - (e.pageX - original_mouse_x)
      console.log(e.target.parentElement);
        e.target.parentElement.style.marginLeft = width + 'px'
    }
    
    function stopResize() {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', resize)
    }
```

```css
.timeblock{
      position: absolute;
      height: 50px;
    }
    .timeblock:hover{
      background: green !important;
    }
    #container{
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="col-xs-12" id="container">
     
    </div>
  </div>
```

It seems the divs don't get resized, what am I doing wrong?
I want to make all divs resizeable by their handlers and move others based on the resize.
Does someone have an example what I can use, cuz I have no clue on how to do this.
Please help me!

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_resize.asp

Comment: No, I need to be able to resize on both sides like an slider